# getting data from a partial view onto main view

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm new to the world of ASP.Net MVC and I'm working with a small application that uses many XML files from a web service as its model data. I have an Html page which contains a list of all the tools that are stored in the XML web services. They are within a loop and are clickable links. I also have a partial view which is just a series of text boxes. My goal is to populate the text boxes with information I get from the tool I click while having the list and the text boxes appear on the same page. I have been successful in doing this but so far have only been able to pass the id to a controller which returns my partial view as a completely new page. I'm sure this is a simple solution which may have been answered on here before. What is the best way to go about solving this problem? Below is my model, view(s) and two controllers

**Tool Model**

```
  public class Tool
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string ToolId { get; set; }
  public string Adapter { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string TNumber { get; set; }
  public List<string> ComponentList { get; set; }
  public List<string> AccessoryList { get; set; }
  public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ToolIdDescription { get; set; }
  public List<string> toolList = new List<string>();

}
```

**Partial View Controller**

```
public ActionResult PartialView()
  {
     Tool newTool = new Tool();
     List<string> tools = new List<string>();
     tools = backgroundLoad();
     newTool.ToolIdDescription = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
     atool.ToolIdDescription = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
     foreach (string tool in tools)
     {
        newTool.ToolIdDescription = GetToolDescription(tool);
     }

     return View(newTool);
  }
```

**Controller to recieve Datasets**

```
public ActionResult GetDataSet(string id)
  {
     Tool selectedTool = new Tool();
     if (id != null)
     {
        var request = 
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/DbService/Tool/" + id);
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        Stream aResponsestream;
        string aResult = "";
        using (aResponsestream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader aReader = new StreamReader(aResponsestream, 
Encoding.UTF8))
        {
           aResult = aReader.ReadToEnd();
           aResponsestream.Close();
        }
        xml.LoadXml(aResult);
        var Description = 
   xml.SelectSingleNode("RetrieveResponse/RetrieveResult/Tool/Description");
        if (Description != null) selectedTool.Description = 
Description.InnerText;
        var Adapter = 
   xml.SelectSingleNode("RetrieveResponse/RetrieveResult/Tool/Adapter/Name");
        if (Adapter != null) selectedTool.Adapter = Adapter.InnerText;
        var TNumber = 
        xml.SelectSingleNode("RetrieveResponse/RetrieveResult/Tool/TNo");
        if (TNumber != null) selectedTool.TNumber = TNumber.InnerText;
        var ToolId = 
        xml.SelectSingleNode("RetrieveResponse/RetrieveResult/Tool/ToolId");
        if (ToolId != null) selectedTool.ToolId = ToolId.InnerText;


        return View(selectedTool);
     }
     else return View();

  }
```

**View which contains the list**

```
@model  MiniWeb.Models.Tool

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<h2>Tool List</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      @foreach (var item in Model.ToolIdDescription)
      {

         <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Key, "GetDataSet", new { id = item.Key })</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)</td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
      }
   </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

@Html.Partial("GetDataSet", new MiniWeb.Models.Tool())
```

**View which displays the tool information**

```
@model MiniWeb.Models.Tool

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetDataSet";
}
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Tool";
}
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>Tool Selection </h2>
<div class="Tool">
   <span id ="id"> 
         @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.ToolId)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.ToolId)
   </span>
   <br/>
   <span id="Description">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Description)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Description)
   </span>
   <br/>
   <span id="Adapter">
         @Html.LabelFor(m=> Model.Adapter)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Adapter)

   </span>
   <br/>
   <span id="Adapter">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.TNumber)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.TNumber)
   </span>
   <span> 
      <button> Save </button>
   </span>
</div>
```

Sorry for all the code but thank you for reading. I also apologize if this is a really easy solution. I'm just new to ASP.Net and want to develop the best practices instead of doing a hack job on it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some more research I was able to figure out how to solve my problem. Turns out all I needed was some AJAX. I used an Ajax.Actionlink instead of an HTML action link and was able to load up my partial view in a div on the page. Here is my new view and controller. The partial view stayed the same.

**View**

```
@model  MiniWeb.Models.Tool

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


   <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Tool List</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      @foreach (var item in Model.ToolIdDescription)
      {

         <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>@Ajax.ActionLink(item.Key, "_Partially", new { id = item.Key },new AjaxOptions()
                {
                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                   UpdateTargetId = "ToolInfo",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,


                })

            </td>


            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)</td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
      }
   </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<div id="ToolInfo">


</div>
```

and my new controller which is returns a PartialView looks like this

**Partial View Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult _Partially(string id)
      {
         Tool selectedTool = new Tool();
         if (id != null)
         {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/DbService/Tool/" + id);

            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            Stream aResponsestream;
            string aResult = "";
            using (aResponsestream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader aReader = new StreamReader(aResponsestream, Encoding.UTF8))


            {
               aResult = aReader.ReadToEnd();
               aResponsestream.Close();
            }
            xml.LoadXml(aResult);
            var Description = xml.SelectSingleNode("RetrieveResponse/RetrieveResult/Tool/Description");
            if (Description != null) selectedTool.Description = Description.InnerText;
            var Adapter = xml.SelectSingleNode("RetrieveResponse/RetrieveResult/Tool/Adapter/Name");
            if (Adapter != null) selectedTool.Adapter = Adapter.InnerText;
            var TNumber = xml.SelectSingleNode("RetrieveResponse/RetrieveResult/Tool/TNo");
            if (TNumber != null) selectedTool.TNumber = TNumber.InnerText;
            var ToolId = xml.SelectSingleNode("RetrieveResponse/RetrieveResult/Tool/ToolId");
            if (ToolId != null) selectedTool.ToolId = ToolId.InnerText;

            return PartialView("_Partially", selectedTool);
         }
         return PartialView();


      }
```

Hopefully this answer will help others like me in the future. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a form on your partial view that will submit the data to the main pages controller.

You can find more information in [this](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Form-Submit-Post-example.aspx) article.